# Laravel One To Many Save Issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'restaurant_id' cannot be
>   null (SQL: insert into `cover_photos` (`path`, `restaurant_id`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
>   (smartmockups_k1gdx0ke_1572876856.jpg, , 2019-11-04 14:14:16,
>   2019-11-04 14:14:16)) ERROR

I am creating a a new restaurant with the name and location. Now it has a cover image which I select it with however when I upload it gives me this error.

the relation is one to many.

RESTAURANT PHOTOS

```
public function coverPhoto()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\CoverPhoto');
    }
```

COVERPHOTO MODEL

```
public function restaurant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Restaurant');
    }
```

Controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Restaurant;
use App\User;
use App\Photo;
use App\CoverPhoto;
class RestaurantController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $restaurants = Restaurant::findOrFail(1)->with('photos', 'coverPhoto')->get();
        //$restaurantCoverPhoto = Restaurant::findOrFail(1)->coverPhoto->get();

        return $restaurants;
        foreach($restaurants as $restaurant){
            echo $restaurant->coverPhoto->path;
        }



        return view('restaurants.restaurants')->with('restaurants', $restaurants);

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('restaurants.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required',
            'cover_photo' => 'image|nullable|max:1999| mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'
        ]);
        // Handle File Upload
        if($request->hasFile('cover_photo')){

            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_photo')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('cover_photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('cover_photo')->storeAs('public/cover_photo', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }
        // Create Post
        $restaurant = new Restaurant;
        $coverPhoto = new CoverPhoto;

        $restaurant->name = $request->input('name');
        $restaurant->location = $request->input('location');

        $coverPhoto->path = $fileNameToStore;
        $coverPhoto->restaurant_id = 1;
        //return $coverPhoto;
        $restaurant->coverPhoto()->save($coverPhoto);

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I think what is happening is that since it is a new restaurant AND a new cover photo, it requires an id to be defined for one or another. Is there a way to create a new Restaurant and a Coverphoto which is a separate db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply save your `$restaurant` first:

```
$restaurant->save();
$restaurant->coverPhoto()->save($coverPhoto);
```

This way when you are inserting `$coverPhoto` via relationship, your `$restaurant` will already be in DB and have it's `id` attribute assigned.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, you should create restaurant and then you can create 
cover photo of restaurant

```
$restaurant = new Restaurant;
$coverPhoto = new CoverPhoto;

$restaurant->name = $request->input('name');
$restaurant->location = $request->input('location');
$restaurant->save();

$coverPhoto->path = $fileNameToStore;

$restaurant->coverPhoto()->save($coverPhoto);
```

Because of whenever you create or insert data in restaurant it's make as a object and then after you can create or insert data in cover photo with restaurant one to one relationship

Comment: I was staring at this code for hours and now realized its so simple...